# CursorAdapter newView/BindView not getting called

Tags: android, android-cursorloader, contentobserver

I m using content observer. Inside onQuery, I have used setNotificationUri to register uri.
In bulkInsert/insert methods, I have added notifyChange method call.
After bulkInsert or insert, CursorLoader.onLoadFinished method is getting called. Inside onLoaderFinished method: adapter.swapCursor is also getting called.
 **But CursorAdapter newView/getView is not getting called.**
 I overrides getCount method as well inside CursorAdapter. I m able to get cursor count. 
 Please help.
 Thanks in advance.

```
MainActivity onCreate contains:
     mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
            mMovieCursorAdapter = new MoviesCursorAdapter(this, null, 0);
            mGridView.setAdapter(mMovieCursorAdapter);


getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(MOVIE_LOADER, null, this);


 @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Uri uri = MovieContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_URI;

        return new CursorLoader(this, uri, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

mMovieCursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mMovieCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }



In ContentProvider query() method:
     retCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

**In bulkInsert() method:**
 getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

Comment: can you share more code and detail

Answer (score 0):

Its maybe late but i had the same problem. My code was running with API 19 as expected but bindView isnt called in API 24. I tried all of the answers about this problem but nothing helped. I controled my code again and again and didnt find any mistakes.

Solution : I created completely a new project. And copied all of the code to new project exactly same as it is. After that in the new project everything worked as expected. I think its somehow related with android studio.

I hope this helps...